# What is the last Nvidia driver for Tesla M2090 video card? Is there a mistake in the official document?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I'm wondering, the official document says, the 440 driver has support for "Fermi" GPUs, also for M2090 too. https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#support-hardware__table-hardware-support

But, it doesn't work on my Ubuntu Server 18.04, it isn't loaded up into kernel. Is this a mistake?

By the way, if you look into supported devices of 410.129 version there: https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/150865/en-us, you will also find M2090, but the driver also doesn't work.

And in the release notes of both versions there is nor about "Fermi" neither about "M2090" support. 
https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-release-notes-410-129/index.html
https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-release-notes-440-3301/index.html

This all is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Use driver 390 (official packages in repos): that's what I use for m2090/c2075